# Please explain the comma operator in this program

Tags: c, comma-operator

Please explain the output of this program:

```
int main()
{    
    int a,b,c,d;  
    a=10;  
    b=20;  
    c=a,b;  
    d=(a,b);  
    printf("\nC= %d",c);  
    printf("\nD= %d",d);  
}
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
C= 10  
D= 20
```

My doubt is what does the  "," operator do here?
I compiled and ran the program using Code Blocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the comma operator \`,\` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `,` operator evaluates a series of expressions and returns the value of the last.

`c=a,b` is the same as `(c=a),b`. That is why c is 10

`c=(a,b)` will assign the result of `a,b`, which is 20, to `c`.

As Mike points out in the comments, assignment (`=`) has higher precedence than comma

Comment: + and `=` has higher precedence than `,`.

Comment: @Eduardo +1 but, although answer for `d=(a,b)` is sort of clear but adding that in your explanation will make your answer complete

Comment: @Eduardo Sir, But what happens if there are 3 values.  
x=(a,b,c,d);
So here the last value (d) is assigned to x?

Comment: @Swamy: That's correct, `d` will be the value assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 12):

Well, this is about operator precedence:

```
c=a,b
```

is

equivalent to

```
(c=a),b
```

The point is, the "," operator will return the second value.

Thus

```
c=a,b
```

assigns a to c and returns b

```
d=(a,b)
```

returns b and assigns it to d

Answer (score 5):

The comma operator evaluates all its operands, then yields the value of the last expression.